# Can I use any string as a JSON property name?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it ok to use any utf-8 string as a JSON property name? I mean is this ok:

```
var personData = {
    'Matti Möttönen': {
        "FirstName": "Matti",
        "LastName": "Möttönen",
    },
...
```

I'm using Vue.js at the moment and the data is coming from flat file.

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Should you do it this way? Probably not. It makes the data harder to access, and you've got needlessly duplicated info in there.

Comment: @ceejayoz how is it harder than literally any other string as key?

Comment: @VLAZ You have to know the person's name to access their name. That's... not optimal.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's a fairly safe bet to say that the name comes from somewhere else as a value. User input or whatever. The data is also hardly duplicate - it breaks down a name into its components which [isn't as simple as getting the first and last part](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). A Japanise name would be in a different order. "Vincent van Gogh" might have a last name of "Gogh" or "van Gogh" depending on his nationality.

Comment: @ceejayoz no, you cannot reconstruct the full name from its parts. Please try it with `{firstName: "Yun Fat", lastName: "Chow"}` and `{firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}`. I'm interested in the algorithm that transforms these into `"Chow Yun Fat"` and `"John Doe"` respectively. Because it sure isn't `p.firstName + " " + p.lastName`

Comment: @VLAZ You'd have to give your desired end results and applicable rules for those. Redundancy aside, I'd rather work in a Vue template using a data structure more akin to `{ "name": { "first": "Matti", "last": "Möttönen", "full": "Something Unusual or Country Specific" }}` than a data structure that mixes up key and value. Like I said; if it's good enough for Facebook - who have likely encountered a lot more name-based rules than I have - I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: @ceejayoz *I gave you the output*. Your claim was that you can transform parts of a name into a full name. I gave you two names in parts and their full name equivalents. Why does your proposed structure contain duplicate data then?

Comment: @VLAZ You can read, right? "Redundancy aside". My proposed format permits a template to do `{{ personData.name.full }}`, `Hi, {{ personData.name.first }}!`, etc. without needing to know the person's name to output it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've read you have a literally magic way of transforming names. I've yet to see it, though. Surely, you can just define `fullName` as a getter that performs said magic which is then trivially cached, so you don't have to repeat the operation.

Comment: Returning from the derailment, the answer to "how is it harder than literally any other string as key" remains "because accessing something like `{{ user.name }}` - whatever the rules for how their name fits together - in a template remains easier than having to *know their name* to display it in the Vue template". I'll rest comfortably that every API I've ever encountered doesn't use the user's name as the key for the user's name data.

Comment: @ceejayoz Then [let me return to what I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216633/can-i-use-any-string-as-a-json-property-name?noredirect=1#comment115295988_65216633) - it's quite safe to assume that the reference would be made as `personData[data]` rather than by `personData.name`. It's a ***very*** standard use case for a lookup map where you get the key from one place and enrich the data from another.

Comment: @VLAZ OP is using Vue. If they're in a template, they might be doing something along the lines of "`Hi, {{ person.firstName }}!`" in the HTML. You're making significant unfounded assumptions on how OP intends to use this info.

Comment: Maybe this was too detailed question (I mean the data)? Should have made it more general / theoretical. But yes, I was just looping the data so the loop always got the right name (no search issues here). Data was coming from the flat file. This was just a test phase code. But very good discussion, thanks to all! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```
var personData = {
    'Matti Möttönen': {
        "FirstName": "Matti",
        "LastName": "Möttönen",
    },
}
```

or even

```
var personData = {
    ['Matti Möttönen']: {
        "FirstName": "Matti",
        "LastName": "Möttönen",
    },
}
```

and you can refer to it as

```
personData['Matti Möttönen']
```

Comment: no need for the `['Matti Möttönen']` when defining the object, `'Matti Möttönen'` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [here](https://javascript.info/object),

> A property is a “key: value” pair, where key is a string (also called a “property name”), and value can be anything.

So to answer your question, as long as you are using strings as key it should be alright.